# Is there a way other than Array / ArrayList for saving elements of matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist

Suppose we have integers as following:
    `(1, 2)=10,`
    `(2,3)=20,`
    `(3, 4)=30`
etc…

These integers are distributed in a matrix with `2000*2000` dimensions.

But I just need 4000-6000 elements of this matrix with their indexes (i.e their position (i, j)). Other elements in matrix are zero. So I don’t need them. 
Is there a good way other than using two dimensional Array/ArrayList, for saving these elements with their indexes, since we can call and reuse the elements and their indexes easily?

Using Array/ArrayList consume alot of memory.

Comment: I'd use some kind of `Map` myself.

Comment: Read up sparse matrix implementations.

Comment: If you are saying array consume lot of memory, in my opinion no other data structure could help you. Arrays are the very basic memory efficient implementation available in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a two-dimensional array of this size would be a waste of memory, because it would have 4,000,000 elements.  Because you only need 4000-6000 elements, this array would be quite sparse.

You can use a `HashMap` that will map a `Point` to an `Integer`.

```
Map<Point, Integer> points = new HashMap<>();
```

You'll need to make sure you have a `Point` class that overrides `hashcode` and `equals` properly.

The `HashMap` would store only the 4000-6000 points that you `put` into it.

Comment: It seems wrong to use `Point` for this - that's really for graphical stuff, where it represents a location in 2D space.  I would either use `HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Integer>` where `Pair` is the Apache Commons one, or `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, Integer>>`.

Comment: @DavidWallace I didn't mean to refer to `java.awt.Point`.  One can create their own `Point` class with appropriate `hashCode` and `equals` methods easily.  But you're right that using `Pair<Integer, Integer>` would work.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with HashMap is pretty good and clean, but if you need linear algebra algorithms it'd be unwise.

You could use [la4j](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j), pure-java open-source linear algebra library. It contains sparse matrix implementations like [Compressed Row Storage](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html) and many matrix algorithms like ranking, decomposition, linear system solving, whatever.

Comment: I would strongly recommend this approach if you are working algebra.